# Does Yii-CGridView column link works when dataProvider used with CSqlDataProvider?

Tags: yii

Code I used in CGridView gives me a null value in $data->gen_id and $data->erc_gen at the column value, when I inspect with the browser inspector it gives me `<a href="/ekportal/erc/index.php?r=ercGen/update&amp;id="></a>`

ercgen/admin code hereunder:

```
$qryTmp = 
    "SELECT gen_id, erc_ref,B.complete_name sales_executive,C.description type,D.client_name client_id,event_name, E.status_desc erc_status ".
    "FROM erc_gen A, Users B, erc_type C, clients D, erc_status E ".
    "WHERE A.sales_executive = b.user_id ".
    "AND A.type = C.typ_no ".
    "AND A.client_id = D.client_id ".
    "AND A.erc_status = E.id ".
    "AND sales_executive = '$user_id' ".
    "AND erc_status = '1' ";
$count = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ('.$qryTmp.') X')->queryScalar();
$dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($qryTmp, array(
'totalItemCount'=>$count,
'sort'=>array(
    'attributes'=>array(
         'gen_id','erc_ref', 'sales_executive', 'type','client_id','event_name','erc_status'
    ),
),
'pagination'=>array(
    'pageSize'=>10,
),
));

//CGRIDVIEW
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'pager'=>array(
    'header'=>'',
    'firstPageLabel'=>'&lt;&lt;',
    'prevPageLabel'=>'&lt;',
    'nextPageLabel'=>'&gt;',
    'lastPageLabel'=>'&gt;&gt;',
),   
'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'header'=>'#',
        'value'=>'$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage * $this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize + ($row+1)',
    ),
    array(
        'header'=>'Reference Number',
        'name'=>'erc_ref',
        'type'=>'raw',
        'value'=>'CHtml::link($data->erc_ref,Yii::app()->createUrl("ercGen/update",array("id"=>"$data->gen_id")))',
    ),
```

Answer (score 3):

I found my answer [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/15669-problem-with-cgridview-columns-when-changing-data-provider/)

Simply changing `$data->erc_ref` to `$data['erc_ref']` and `$data->gen_id` to `$data['gen_id']`